# Splitting a full name + numbers into into 3 cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split the following data (using VBA)

An example of the text I have is below

```
Scott Hamilton 1/2
```

I would like to display it like this on the same line

```
A15 Scott Hamilton
B15 1
C15 2
```

The cell always contains a name (first and last) and then there stats ie 1 of 2

I would like to split as above

Hope someone can help - Have attached a picture of some of my data (as this will have other text already on the sheet which I cannot move/change)

http://i40.tinypic.com/riyq9x.jpg

Edit:

Sorry forgot to add my attempt;

```
Sub SplitName()
Dim SplitName() As String
SplitName = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(15, 1).Value)
Cells(15, 1) = SplitName(0) + " " + SplitName(1)
Cells(15, 2) = SplitName(2)
Cells(15, 3) = SplitName(3)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way...

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFraction As String

    Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find("/", , xlValues, xlPart)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        Do
            strFraction = Trim(Right(Replace(WorksheetFunction.Trim(rngFound.Text), " ", String(99, " ")), 99))

            rngFound.Resize(, 3).Value = Array(Trim(Replace(rngFound.Text, strFraction, "")), _
                                               Split(strFraction, "/")(0), _
                                               Split(strFraction, "/")(1))

            Set rngFound = Columns("A").Find("/", rngFound, xlValues, xlPart)
        Loop While Not rngFound Is Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: WOW Thanks so much! I dont fully understand the code yet (still going through each step) - But it is working perfectly!!!!! for Column A

Answer (score 1):

I think first you need to split string before you find number. So first you need to get string occuring before number. In your case you split string before number occurs.
So you will get 2 strings as

```
Scott Hamilton and 1/2
```

Then split remaining string with seperator as "/"

So try like below

```
Dim str As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strArray() As String

str = ActiveCell.Value

For i = 1 To Len(str)

  If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then

    LeftString = Left(str, i – 1)
    RightString = Right(str, Len(str) – i + 1)

    Exit For
  End If
Next i
```

Now split RightString with "/"

So do below

```
 strArray = Split(RightString , "/")
```

This will seperate text `1/2`

Hope you got the idea. I haven't tested this code. This is just idea which should work.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. I cannot seem to get it going. Getting an error when setting the Left and Right Strings - It also seems like some complex code for my level! So hard for me to find out what is wrong excatly

Comment: synax error :     LeftString = Left(str, i – 1)
    RightString = Right(str, Len(str) – i + 1)

Comment: @PradipDahya do you know how to use left and right functions?

Comment: @PradipDahya Also did you understood what i tried to mention.

Comment: We are trynig to split the string (ie the name) to the leftstring, and the numbers "1/2" etc into RightString?

Comment: @PradipDahya yes we are splitting string into 2 parts

Comment: Is the syntax error from "i - 1" trying to change the variable while in the left command? (same for right)

Comment: @PradipDahya what value you get for variable i

Comment: Dim str As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strArray() As String

str = ("A1")

For i = 1 To Len(str)

  If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then

    LeftString = Left(str, i)
    RightString = Right(str, 4)
Cells(1, 1) = LeftString
Cells(1, 2) = RightString
Cells(1, 1) = i
    Exit For
  End If
Next i

End Sub

Displays i as 2

Comment: @PradipDahya Why did you remove i-1 when using left?

Comment: Hey, Your code shows "Syntax error" - This line:   LeftString = Left(str, i – 1) and this line:     RightString = Right(str, Len(str) – i + 1)

Comment: @PradipDahya so if you use LeftString = Left(str, i), you might be getting Leftstring as "A1", am i correct?

Comment: I am not sure-   I just removed the "-1" just to run the code, but it doesnt display anywhere as we havent told it to yet

Comment: @PradipDahya what do you mean when you say you are not sure? Just put break point and check what value you get in variable LeftString

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you mean break point? As you can see from my code im not very skilled at VBA yet. Which is why I am having problems getting your code going.

Comment: "    LeftString = Left(str, i)
    Cells(1, 1) = LeftString" will display "Scott Hamilton 1"

Comment: Which software you use to write this code? Are you writing macro or using visual studio?

Comment: macro/module with excel

Comment: `If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
    i = i - 1
    LeftString = Left(str, i)
    Cells(1, 1) = LeftString
    i = i + 1
    x = Len(str) - i + 1
    RightString = Right(str, x)
    Cells(1, 2) = x`

Comment: `Dim str As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strArray() As String

str = ActiveCell.Value

For i = 1 To Len(str)

  If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
    i = i - 1
    LeftString = Left(str, i)
    Cells(1, 1) = LeftString
    i = i + 1
    x = Len(str) - i + 1
    RightString = Right(str, x)
  
  
  strArray = Split(RightString, "/")
  Cells(1, 2) = strArray(0)
   Cells(1, 3) = strArray(1)
   
    Exit For
  End If
Next i`

This seems to work now!! But now I need it to automatically do the whole of column A?

Comment: What is whole of column A?

Comment: at the moment we are only changing 'Active Cell' I want to select A:A and run the macro over that ?

Comment: Cant u loop through cells?

Comment: Send me your macro at nandedkar.kiran@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks! I have emailed you now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start, but here are a few suggestions:
1. You might name your string as something different than the subroutine. Naming both as splitname is bad practice here.
2. Using the split function without stating a delimiter means `split` does its work based on a space (" "), so it will not split **1/2** into **1** and **2**.
3. You say you would like to display on the same line, but in row A, B, C. If you want displayed in seperate rows, the first portion of `cells` should change, not the second portion.

Comment: Thanks - I have renamed the var's - I want them on the same Row, just different cells - (ie A1, B1, C1) - So would I use two splits? The second split to split the numbers? (first the spaces)

Comment: Yes, the split function can only use one delimeter at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will continue trying to modify AshReva's code from above

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SplitName()
     Dim Cell As Range, LastSpace As Long
     Set Cell = ActiveSheet.Cells(15, 1)
     LastSpace = InStrRev(Cell.Text, " ")
     Cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).Value = Split(Mid(Cell.Text, LastSpace + 1), "/")
     Cell.Value = Left(Cell.Text, LastSpace - 1)
End Sub
```

This is solution for cell <kbd>A15</kbd>, I assume you can generalize operation.

Comment: Thank you - That is indeed working for A15 - But I have no idea how to create a successful loop for the whole of column A. One thing about your code - It is setting the numbers of the cells as text not numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( window ).load(function() {
            jQuery("#FullNametest").change(function(){
                var temp = jQuery(this).val();
                var fullname = temp.split(" ");
                var firsname='';
                var middlename='';
                var lastname = '';
                firstname=fullname[0];
                lastname=fullname[fullname.length-1];

                for(var i=1; i < fullname.length-1; i++) 
                {
                   middlename =  middlename +" "+ fullname[i];
                }
                jQuery('#FirstName').val(firstname);
                jQuery('#middlename').val(middlename);
                jQuery('#LastName').val(lastname);
            });
        });
```